# fopen() works, dio_open() doesn't?

Tags: php, file, fopen

Seeing some issues running [**fopen()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) when [**dio_open()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dio-open.php) is working just fine. Here's a test script I wrote to check the issue as it was appearing in a new installation I'm trying to get working.

```
<?php
        echo "Current User: " . get_current_user() . "<br/>";
        echo "UID: " . getmyuid() . "<br/>";
        echo "GID: " . getmygid() . "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        $foTest = fopen("test.txt","r");
        echo fread($foTest,4);

        $fd = dio_open('test.txt', O_RDONLY);
        $read = dio_read($fd);
        echo $read;
        $file = dio_open('test.txt', O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
?>
```

The script outputs the following:

> Current User: infinitywhack UID: 1004 GID: 1002
>
> test Warning: dio_open(): cannot open file test.txt with flags 0 and
>   permissions 0: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/infinity.whacknet.com/public_html/test.php on line 9
>
> Warning: dio_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in /var/www/infinity.whacknet.com/public_html/test.php on line 10
>
> Warning: dio_open(): cannot open file test.txt with flags 65 and
>   permissions 0: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/infinity.whacknet.com/public_html/test.php on line 12

This shows the user and group (infinitywhack:www) which is correct. The "test" output here is the content of the test.txt file, that is the code that is running with fopen(). The errors are only given by dio functions.

Here are the permissions for both files:

```
[root@death public_html]# ls -la test.*
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 infinitywhack www 342 May 12 23:36 test.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 infinitywhack www   5 May 12 23:06 test.txt
```

I've been scratching my head all night on this one, there's very little documentation on anything dio from what I have found. Very little saying what is needed here. The only thing I could think of was suExec but there aren't any directives in use that would cause this, although surely those same directives would fail for fopen as well if that were the case?

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Comment: is it possible dio_open doesn't read relative paths? What happens if you try it with a fully qualified path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think STLMikey & Ahmet are on the right track.

Try `dio_open(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'test.txt', ...)`

In this [source code](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/dio/trunk/dio.c?view=markup) at least, `dio_open` makes no attempt to construct an absolute path. The `filename` parameter is passed to the operating system unchanged.

The `No such file or directory` & `Permission denied` errors are coming from the OS, not the dio library. So it seems likely your server is looking for `test.txt` in the wrong place.

Comment: GAH! I can't believe I didn't think of that! That's exactly what it was! dio was trying to read the file /test.txt instead of <webroot>/test.txt. I tested this by setting the referenced file in full on the script which then correctly read the file and output the contents.

Answer (score -1):

firsty make sure your file is exist.
Also your php file permissions should be 0777 to create file
and you can add a folder to set permission "777" automaticly by this command

```
$folder=mkdir( "yourdirname", 0777);
```

And than you should try to understand the problem

```
 $file="test.txt";
    //maybe your server cannot find the root
    // if it does not solve the problem write root file command
// $file=dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."test.txt";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
       //its ok try to continue
    } else {
        echo "the text file is not exits !";
    }
```